# jQuery and codeigniter help

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get some data from a database on the fly and place it into a `div`, currently my javascript file looks like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //accordians for when the AJAX loads the content

    // hides the main_menu as soon as the DOM is ready
    // (a little sooner than page load)
    $('#main_menu').hide();
        // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('h3#show-menu a').click(function() {
                $('#main_menu').toggle('slow');
                    return false;
        });
//try and hide the left content when it is null
    $("#left-content:empty").hide();
    //style up the scroll bar
        $('#left-content').jScrollPane();

        //do some AJAX to call the method instead of the browser
        $("a.navlink").click(function (ev) {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            ev.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("id")
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
               $("."+id).remove();
            } else {
            //$(this).toggleClass("active");
                  var url = $(this).attr("href");
                alert(url);
                    $.ajax ({
                        url:  url,
                        type: "POST",
                        success : function (html) {
                            $('#accordion').accordion('destroy');
                            $("#accordion").append(html).accordion({active:false, header:'h2', collapsible:true});
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
        /*
                * THIS IS CODE IN QUESTION
                */
        $("a.contentlink").mouseover(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax ({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                success : function (html) {
                    $('#abstract').append(html)
                }
            });
        });
  });
</script>
```

The code in question is last function that uses `a.contentlink` as the selector, what I am wanting is for the user to enter the the element with their mouse and for that to trigger the ajax and the results to be appended to the `#abstract' container, the method gets called is currently,

```
public function get_content($content_id) {
        $data['hello'] = "hello";
        $this->load->view('template/abstract', $data);
    }
```

At the moment I am just setting a simple variable when the function is called, but I am getting nothing back, can any body help?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on where get_content is called from. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code in your first listing. What is the content returned by the URL used in your mouseover ajax call?

Comment: get content is called from the URL of the link that mouseentered

Comment: Can you test that the AJAX call is working by attempting to load a different URL that is a simple, static HTML page instead of the CodeIgniter page? My guess is that your problem is something in CodeIgniter, not in the Javascript. Also, can you drop an `alert(html)` into the `success` callback to see what it produces?

Comment: P.S. Firebug and Firefox are great for debugging AJAX calls as you can see the call and the response including any errors or 404 messages :-)

Comment: Thanks Topher, got it working I was loading in my view that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the following code

```
$this->load->view('template/abstract', $data, TRUE);
```

the output is returned which is what you need for AJAX requests.

Source: Returning views as data, http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

Not correct - the last arg true needed only if you're placing the view into a variable. Exp:
$view = $this->load->view('template/abstract', $data, TRUE); and then you can echo $view;

Comment: This doesn't seem like a constructive answer, mind editing it?

Answer (score 0):

According Codeigniter (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html):

Returning views as data

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);

Meaning that the 3rd parameter is used when placing the view into a variable. By default it takes FALSE...